# is quicker to use array_keys() in a foreach statemnt or set a value variable that's never used?

Tags: php, performance

Suppose I want to iterate over an array and either I never look at the values, or I am setting things in them, so I only want the keys. Which is quicker:

```
// Set a variable each iteration which is unused.
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $array[$key]['foo'] = 'bar';
}

// Call array_keys() before iterating.
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
  $array[$key]['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

Comment: @AshleyBanks: Why wouldn't he?

Comment: I'm not sure why he wouldn't either - that's why I was asking what he would be using this for.

Comment: Really some microseconds count? If this is not the case, then code in a way you are comfortable with and you rememeber what the code is doing. Think in the long term.

Comment: @AshleyBanks: Why not? There are lots of circumstances where one needs to iterate over an array, and it's only the keys that are of interest in that particular foreach loop.

Answer (score 13):

I think this would also work, and may be quicker:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
  $value['foo'] = 'bar';
}
```

UPDATE: I did a little test, and it seems this is faster.  http://codepad.org/WI7Mtp8K

Comment: +1 for elegance. Although isn't passing by reference implied in PHP > 5.2?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Not in a foreach loop.

Comment: It's not passing by reference, it's avoiding the copy on read. `foreach` creates the copy of the array element, but if prepended with referencing operator - it doesn't do it. Hence, foreach becomes faster and PHP uses less memory.

Comment: remember to unset($value) after you terminate your loop

Comment: @Rocket, interesting. I always knew there was a *memory overhead* to a foreach loop from back in the day. Now I know why and how to avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this answer is relevant here. It's interesting, but doesn't apply to the question, as here you've only got the values of the array, not the keys.

Comment: @joachim: You don't need the keys of the array.  Notice the `&` before `$value`.  What's happening here is that `$value` is a *reference* to every the current element in the array.  When you write to it, the array element is updated.

Comment: I do need the keys. The example code I gave for the loop isn't representative of what I was actually doing with my own code. The keys are IDs of items, the actual items are irrelevant to the loop code.

Comment: @joachim: You're aware that this answer and its question are 4 years old, right?  What I wrote was just a suggestion based on what was shown.  If you didn't show the *real* code or explain what you were really trying to do, then I wouldn't've known that.  Also, you can probably just ask a new question if this is still an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving aside that the second example is contrived. Meaning, as **Ashley Banks** noted, *why would you be doing this*?

The first example would be more performant of the two. The second has the overhead of the additional function call to `array_keys()`.

Check out the [PHP Benchmark](http://www.phpbench.com/) for additional performance tests. When in doubt, benchmark it yourself with [`microtime()`](http://php.net/microtime).

Answer (score 2):

People need to stop prioritizing questioning the motive of the OP.

I did a simple microtime test and noticed barely any noteable difference in execution time.

The method - creating the test-array:

```
$arr = array();
for($i = 0; $i<10000; $i++){
    $arr[] = mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
    //NOTE: I also tested setting values in random keys, no measurable difference
}
```

Then use that array for testing:

```
//Method 1
$start = microtime(true);
foreach(array_keys($arr) as $k){
    $arr[$k] = 0; //Do something
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'we spent '.($end - $start).' seconds doing this.';
```

Here is the code for the other method testing (ran this separately, or results varied even more)

```
//Method 2
$start = microtime(true);
foreach($arr as $k => $v){
    $arr[$k] = 0; //Do something
}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'we spent '.($end - $start).' seconds doing this.';
```

My timings were around 2 milliseconds runtime for both. I guess my system isn't stable enough for consistent measures of microseconds.
I could not determine if one was faster than the other.

I also tested running each foreach 1000 times with a smaller array to measure the method itself, but I just got the same 2 milliseconds result.

**So what does this mean?** 
Based on these simple tests, the choice of method is pointless in regards to performance.
Maybe you can measure a tiny improvement with one method over another if you are running extremely large arrays on extremely stable systems, or running extremely many foreach-loops the one way the other.